# how do you annotate type in HList

Tags: haskell, hlist

I'm trying to use HList and I need to annotate it but I can't figure out how to do it.

If if type the following in ghci

```
>:t "hello" .*. HNil
```

I got the following type signature :

HList ((':) * [Char] ('[] *))

Which I don't really understand. If try to use this signature I got an error

> "hello" .*. HNil :: HList ((':) * [Char] ('[] *))

I got an error

```
<interactive>:21:15: parse error on input `:'
```

What should I do ?

(I've seen things using `:*:` so I could in theory do `String :*: HNil` but it can't find `:*:`.

Comment: `:*:` was removed in HList 0.3 because `':` is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way certain type signatures are printed in older versions of ghc are quite bad. The type `HList ((':) * [Char] ('[] *))` really means `HList ( ([Char] :: *) ':  ('[] :: *) )`. But this probably isn't very clear either, so lets go through it:

- `[Char] :: *`   A list of char, whose [kind](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism.html) (the type of a type) is `*`, which is the kind of things which have values. This type comes from the type of `"hello"`
- `'[] :: *` The type representing the empty type level list. The type that the compiler print is actually *wrong* - the kind of `'[]` isn't `*`, it is `[*]` - the same way that you cons `a` and `[a]` with `:`. This type comes from the type of `HNil`.
- `':` Equivalent of `:` but for type level lists. This comes from the type of `.*.`

You can't give the type signature back because it is simple invalid. But any of the following would be correct:

```
"hello" .*. HNil :: HList ([Char] ': '[])
"hello" .*. HNil :: HList ( ([Char] :: *) ': ('[] :: [*]))
"hello" .*. HNil :: HList '[ String ]
"hello" .*. HNil :: HList '[ (String :: *) ]
```

You *can't* write the type level list cons prefix - I would assume this is a bug in the parser:

```
>"hello" .*. HNil :: HList ( (':) String '[])

<interactive>:4:31: parse error on input `:'
```

The explicit kind annotations are unnecessary, but you can put them in anyways.

The printing was improved in ghc 7.8:

```
>:t "hello" .*. HNil
"hello" .*. HNil :: HList '[[Char]]
```

Comment: That works. However it needs the `DataKinds` extension.

Comment: `"hello" .*. HNil :: HList ( '(:) String '[])` works. Still, I'm not sure there's a good reason why `(':)` doesn't work.